# Getting Error while moving from portrait to landscape in ios xcode Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Below is the Error occur when I move portrait to landscape mode table running perfect, but when I hide the table and moves to the second table. it shows error like below. but the same project running perfectly in portrait mode while moving first table view to the another.Having a problem in landscape only.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EI_Detail_TableViewCell Maintanace_M__tbl_lbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe21a0c1a00'

Thank you.

Comment: what is Maintanace_M__tbl_lbl and where is it declared ?

Comment: Both are UItable and both running perfect in portrait  but not running perfect in landscape

Comment: I am doing the show and hide on button click.

Comment: the error says there is no Maintanace_M__tbl_lbl method on EI_Detail_TableViewCell

Comment: Yes, but the same thing running perfectly in portrait mode.

Comment: **I Found the Error solution**, I have the same cell identifier for both the table. When I change the cell identifier. Now it's Working.